# Inserting selected CheckBoxList values in to db

Tags: c#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("mydatasource");

        string cbspecialities = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                cbspecialities += li.Value + ", ";
            }
        }

        conn.Open();

        string sql = "Insert into tblml (Names) VALUES('" + cbspecialities + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

it is not inserting in to the table ..

where is the problem ?

Please help

Thnks

Comment: first check  if you got a new row with empty Names in table tblml

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Is the SQL query being executed at all?  Are there any values in `cbspecialties`?  Are there any error messages?  Inspect the runtime behavior of this and give us some more information.

Comment: Did you get error messages? How do you check that there is no new record? Are you sure that you are looking at the right database?

Comment: Side-note: you can shorten the code: `string cbspecialities=string.Join(",", CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li=>li.Selected).Select(li=>li.Value));`. This also prevents the trailing comma at the end.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: The prooblem is there ino any value in cbspecialties ,  i debug it but shows null .

Comment: Yes I am getting empty names in tblml

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert multiple values in one record, instead of "values (value)", do "values (val1), (val2), .. (valn)"

Comment: so is it gonna be like cbL1.items[i].text ? But i want to insert only choosen ones in to db .

Comment: He just tries to insert a single value (a varchar which contains values separated by comma but still a single value).

Comment: yes , iwant to insert selected values in a single column.Is this the rright way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should be in the format

```
INSERT INTO tblml (NAMES) VALUES
(Value1), 
(Value2)
```

Currently your SQL produces something like

```
INSERT INTO tblml (NAMES) VALUES
(Value1,Value2,)
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: For now , i am learninng it is logic  , like , how it works .But thanks for your warning .

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `,` to anything else like `-`

Change:

```
cbspecialities += li.Value + ", ";
```

To:

```
cbspecialities += li.Value + "- ";
```

Comment: It is not working neither . MY DB Table looks like this :             id | Names  and i want to insert choosen values in Names column.

Comment: Ok, before the insert statement, can you try `MessageBox.Show(cbspecialities.toString());` and tell me the output